# How to create smooth surface (skin) for a model made of beams?

Tags: mesh

I need some help here.

I am interested in a model here:
https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/character/woman/ballerina-dancer-abstract-sculpture-6

This model is made of connected cubes and beams, but I need to use the model with smooth skin. May I ask what is the best approach to create smooth skin for this model?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best way forward is to either contact the producer of that model (they may have a version with smooth skin rather than the cubes and beams) or to reproduce a similar model and pose using a model created with a tool such as [MakeHuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MakeHuman)  or the [Manuel Bastioni](http://www.manuelbastioni.com/) Lab add-on (although that looks to have been discontinued... however, there's a community supported branch available at https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab/wiki).